# crash when objectForKey("Id") Id is not there?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, null, alamofire

Im using alamofire for http requests in my iOS app. When i access a value in response like following in Swift it get crash if key is not there or when getting a null value.

```
  var id = (response.result.value?[p-1].objectForKey("Id"))! as? Int
```

In general how can we check for a value which is not exist in Swift?

Answer (score 2):

You should try this

```
if let id = (response.result.value?[p-1].objectForKey("Id"))? as? Int {
   // some stuff
}
```

Your application is crashing because you unwrapped nil object: .objectForKey("Id")

Comment: Make it `if let id = response.result.value?[p-1].objectForKey("Id") as? Int` and this is the best answer.

Comment: You are right @overactor, I paste his code, parenthesis are useless

Answer (score 0):

You have to unwrap your optionals without forcing it. In your case, you should also think about checking whether `response.result.value` has at least `p-1` elements:

```
if let value = response.result.value
{
   if p-1 < value.count
   {
       if let id = value[p-1].objectForKey("Id") as? Int
       {
           // Do whatever you want with id
       }
   }
}
```

You can also use `guard` statement that I personally find clearer:

```
guard let value = response.result.value
   else { return }
guard p-1 < value.count
   else { return }
guard let id = value[p-1].objectForKey("Id") as? Int
   else { return }

// Do whatever you want with id
```

Comment: You're not using optional chaining as well as you could, have a look at @ArnaudWurmel's answer for an example.

Comment: I know, I decomposed the optional chain to make it clearer for OP.